# Can I simplify the inequality "distance(p1, p2) < distance(p1, p3)?"

Tags: vector

I am working on some vector logic, so am asking: can I save processor time by simplifying this inequality:

```
distance(vector1, vector2) < distance(vector1, vector3)
```

I see that `vector1` is repeated in both cases.

Comment: Just a quick note: your current method is very readable and its function can be instantly understood.  Some of these answers may accomplish the task you have requested, but are much less clear.  This is fine if performance is of the essence, but make sure to comment it properly to account for the loss of clarity.

Comment: To continue @MikeS's comment, performance should only be of the essence in cases like this if you have already done analysis or profiling and have identified this call as a bottleneck. Maintainability beats out raw performance if we're talking the difference between 305fps and 303fps.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes**, you can simplify this. First, stop calling them vectors. They are points. Let’s call them `A`, `B` and `C`.

So, you want this:

```
dist(A, B) < dist(A, C)
```

Replace distances with distances squared, then with dot products (from the definition of the [Euclidean length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_length). Replace `AC` with `AB + BC` (now these are real vectors). Expand, simplify, factor:

```
dist(A, B)² < dist(A, C)²
dot(AB, AB) < dot(AC, AC)
dot(AB, AB) < dot(AB + BC, AB + BC)
dot(AB, AB) < dot(AB, AB) + dot(BC, BC) + 2 dot(AB, BC)
0 < dot(BC, BC) + 2 dot(AB, BC)
0 < dot(BC + 2 AB, BC)
```

There you are:

```
dot(AB + AC, BC) > 0
```

With your vector notation:

```
dot(v2 - v1 + v3 - v1, v3 - v2) > 0
```

That’s a few additions and one dot product instead of the previous two dot products.

Comment: Can you explain how you can replace a*a + b*b = a*a + c*c with the dot product version?

Comment: @TravisG I am not sure of what you are asking. If your question is why `dist(A, B)²` is the same as `dot(AB, AB)`, it comes from the very definition of the [Euclidean length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_length).

Comment: Clearly this does (somewhat) simplify the equation mathematically, but wouldn't necessarily "save processor time" for the OP. It results in more complexity and more calculations than just removing the square root from the original distance equations.

Comment: Correct me if i´m wrong but the two dot-products are 5 operations per dot-product plus the two vec3 substractions which is a total of 16 operations, your way has 3 vec3 substractions plus an Addition which makes 12 operations plus the dot product makes 17.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the result is the dot-product of the two opposite diagonals of a parallelogram.   But that is irrelevant.  What I wanted to say is that there isn't a tremendous amount to be gained from this *full* simplification; as others have mentioned it does a decent amount to obfuscate or complicate what you're actually trying to calculate.  However, you definitely want to use the first step.  Avoiding an unnecessary square root is always worth it.  Just comparing the Squares of the distances is the same, as distance is positive definite, even in the complex plane.

Comment: You have four additions, so `4*dimension` additions total. I'm not sure what's better: `d` more multiplications or `2*d` more additions? I think this is an unsatisfactory answer; what Byte56 did is straightforward, and this doesn't even leave me convinced that it's any faster! (Also, if we don't care about the distinction between affine spaces and vector spaces, insisting that vectors and points are distinct only gets in the way of understanding. Personal opinion/peeve.)

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy Oh, I’m not claiming it’s faster, I’m just claiming it’s simpler :) A for insisting that vector and points are distinct, my opinion is that sloppiness gets in the way of understanding.

Comment: @SamHocevar Sure, I agree, but what does that have to do with points and vectors? ;)

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy for instance, adding weighted vectors together always has a meaning, whereas most of the time adding points together is only meaningful if the sum of weights is 0 or 1. Knowing this helps avoiding mistakes in calculations.

Answer (score 16):

**Yes.** Assuming your `distance` function uses a square root, you can simplify this by removing the square root.

When trying to find the larger (or smaller) of a distance, `x^2 > y^2` still holds true for `x > y`.

However, further attempts to simplify the equation mathematically are likely pointless. The distance between `vector1` and `vector2` is not the same as the distance between `vector1` and `vector3`. While the equation can be simplified mathematically as [Sam's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/60777/7191) shows, the form it's currently in is likely as simple as you'll get from the processor usage perspective.

Comment: I don't have enough rep, but I would as it is fundamentally incorrect, I believe: "can I save processor time by simplifying this inequality?" The answer is yes.

Comment: The answer is only yes if the distance equation is using a square root. Which I mention.

Comment: Valid point, I'd retract my statement. However, it is 99% guaranteed that the user means euclidean distance sqrt(sum(dimensional differences squared))

Comment: @imsoconfused Fair enough, I've changed the order of my answer to state the most likely (99%) scenario first.

Comment: Yes, my experience is when you're dealing with this sort of stuff a DistanceSquared function is very useful.  It's just as clear and avoids the expensive sqrt operation.

Answer (score 0):

Some maths could help.

What you are trying to do is:

```
<v1, v2> < <v1, v3> =>
sqrt((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2) < sqrt((y3-y1)^2+(x3-x1)^2) =>
y2^2 - 2*y2y1 + y1^2 + x2^2 - 2*x2x1 + x1^2 < y3^2 - 2*y3y1 + y1^2 + x3^2 - 2*x3x1 + x1^2
```

From what you can remove repeated variables and group some others. The operation that you have to check is:

```
y3^2 - y2^2 - 2*y1(y3-y2) + x3^2 - x2^2 - 2*x1(x3-x2) > 0
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

*The real question* seems to be how to reduce computation for determining the nearest object?

*Optimising* this is often done in games, although with all optimisations it should be profile-guided and, often, doesn't *simplify* things.

The way to avoid unnecessary distance computations to determine the nearest thing - or all things within a certain range - is to use a *spatial index* e.g. an [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

This only pays off if there are a large number of objects.  For just three objects, it is unlikely to pay off and certainly doesn't *simplify* the code.

Comment: I think the actual question is fairly straightforward, and this answer doesn't address that. If you wanted to speculate as to the OP's deeper, unstated questions that should really be done as a comment if you aren't going to actually answer the asked question.

Comment: I am downvoting this because invoking a possible premature optimization is __not__ an answer to a problem where _explicit_ optimization does not hurt either readability, code maintainability, nor does it encourage obscure practices. When you can actually write simple and optimized code, why not do it? It certainly does not hurt to do it, even if you have a higher level plan (no game developer will ever refuse some extra microseconds per frame, esp. on consoles).

Comment: @teodron: *"When you can actually write simple and optimized code, why not do it?"* - Because OP *(and now, us)* has now spent a non-negligable amount of time optimizing something which may give him no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I agree with this to be a minor (hence insignificant optimization if used for a few hundred calls per frame, but if the factor of magnitude increases to thousands, things surely change). However, we are all free not to waste time trying to answer/optimize something we deem as not viable. The OP asked for one thing, people assumed the OP was not aware of higher level strategies and profiling practices. I personally prefer to make such remarks in comments, not in answers. Sorry for being so verbose :(.

Answer (score -3):

it depends on what the output of distance(v1,v2) is

if it is a decimal (float or double) over a vector it is likely that distancesquared would be a lot quicker

Comment: I don't see what it being a `float` has to do with anything.

Comment: i meant a float over another vector just not explained particularly well (and i think you knew that)

Comment: I wasn't intentionally misunderstanding. I'm still not sure what you mean. I don't know why a distance function would return a vector.